# Pardot basic email and Engagement studio

Tags: pardot

I can't seem to find a good answer for this. I am looking to create "basic" emails (ie look like they are coming from a normal esp) in the new Pardot email builder. Is that possible? All I have been able to do is create emails with a lot of padding on the left and right that do not look like they are coming from an individual. Great for mass emails but not for more personalized contact.

I am able to achieve this on the "Pardot Email" (classic builder) but it appears I cannot use those email in the engagement studio and also I have read that the classic builder is being phased out.

Any advice is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: The body of the email in the lightning email builder has right and left padding. Could it be they are set with a big value ? You can use emails built with the old builder in engagement studio, but you must use an email template to do so.

Comment: Can you use both emails built in the old builder and emails built in the new builder is the same engagement program?

Comment: Yes, you can. Both "activated for automation" lighting emails and standard templates declared as "engagement program email" are displayed in the email activity of ES.